# Multiple id in a single row

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Business Model and a Category Model.
Business belongs_to multiple category. What I am trying to do is building the relation without help of a third join table.

In business table there is a string column which will hold the comma separated category_id.

So I am wondering is it possible to build the relation like that. Any wise comment and idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Just saying, using a third join table would make it much easier in the future to filter/group businesses by category. If you don't want to play with tables yourself you might want to use act-as-taggable-on and male your model acts_as_taggable_on :categories so you can find business tagged with 'category' or find how many businesses are in one or another category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to do it with just a method:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  def categories
    @categories ||= Category.where(id: category_ids.split(',')) 
  end

  def category_ids=(ids)
    # this is needed to reset the memoization, when you change the category ids
    @categories = nil
    super
  end
end
```